# What's the meaning of '&' and '!' before property name?

Tags: wix

I am reading WIX script written by others. There are some code really confuses me.

```
<Custom Action='UnLoadSchedulerPerfCounters' After='InstallInitialize'>
    <![CDATA[(Installed) AND (!Scheduler = 3)]]>
</Custom>
<Custom Action='RollbackSchedulerPerfCounters' After='WriteRegistryValues'>
        <![CDATA[(&Scheduler = 3)]]>
</Custom>
```

So, what's the difference between `!Scheduler` and `&Scheduler`?
Is any special meaning when property is prefix-ed by `&` or `!`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson5.php#5.3:

> Prepending some special characters to
>   the names will give them extra
>   meaning:
>
> ```
> %     environment variable (name is case insensitive)
> $     action state of component
> ?     installed state of component
> &     action state of feature
> !     installed state of feature
> ```
>
> The last four can return the following
>   integer values:
>
> ```
> -1   no action to be taken
> 1    advertised (only for components)
> 2    not present
> 3    on the local computer
> 4    run from the source
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Those are operators on the Windows Installer condition syntax. See this MSI SDK documentation for a complete list:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012.aspx.